# How to fix Signal Handler assignment

Tags: c, linux, signals, handler, sigaction

For Linux C programming, I have this handler and main method:

```
void handler(int number, signinfo_t, void *ignore){
    printf("Signaling %d\n", si->si_pid);
}

int main(){
    struct sigaction sig;
    sig.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigemptyset(&sig.sa_mask);
    sig.sa_handler = handler // This line has error
```

If I make the handler with just 1 parameter `void handler(int num)`
it works fine; however, I will not be able to use `si->si_pid`. The warning I am getting is :

```
 warning: assignment to __sighandler_t from an incompatible pointer type
 -Wincompatible-pointer-types
 sig.sa_handler = handler;
```

Do I make it `sig.sa_action` instead? I want to fix the warning

Comment: Note:you cannot use `printf()` (and friends) from within a signal handler.

Comment: You're missing a variable name in the `handler` function definition. Did you mean to write `siginfo_t *si`?

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning the handler function to the wrong member of `sig`. The declaration of `struct sigaction` is:

```
struct sigaction {
    void     (*sa_handler)(int);
    void     (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
    sigset_t   sa_mask;
    int        sa_flags;
    void     (*sa_restorer)(void);
};
```

`sig.sa_handler` is a function with only one argument, the signal number. When you use the `SA_SIGINFO` flag, you need to assign the 3-argument function to `sig.sa_sigaction` instead.

```
int main(){
    struct sigaction sig;
    sig.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigemptyset(&sig.sa_mask);
    sig.sa_sigaction = handler;
```

Comment: I did that, now it says struct sigaction has no member named "sa_action"

Comment: It's `sa_sigaction`, not `sa_action`.